# Server-side rendering for search engines only (SEO)

Tags: seo, javascript

I have a heavily JavaScript based web app which I want to make it indexable.

I know that google bot and others agents can already see JavaScript, but I don't trust they will capture my content correctly and the problem is even bigger with asynchronous JavaScript. For examples: there are sections that are loaded only when the user scrolls down. There are also crawlers that can't see JavaScript, like Facebook's crawler.

Can I just send pre-rendered HTML, using phantomjs or other headless browser, to the google bot? This would be exactly what my end-users sees, but my fear is I may suffer penalties for serving different content for the bots.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can I just send pre-rendered HTML, using phantomjs or other headless
>   browser, to the google bot?

In short... no you shouldn't. Google's stance on differing versions for visitors and search bots is clear and regardless of your intentions it is classed as a cloak. Google also goes to great lengths to activity look for sites that specifically treat the Googlebot differently to other website visitors.

*All sites should render the same with both Googlebot and Users*

Every site regardless of the JavaScript should be render the same by both users and search engines, if it does not then there is something wrong with your site.

*Emulating what Googlebot sees...*

You can emulate and render what Googlebot sees when visiting your site by using the [Google's Fetch Test](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6066468?hl=en) with Google search console, with the results provided you can debug your site and ensure that its read and renders as expected  for both search bots and users.

Comment: I don't think that's true anymore. Google itself proposes SSR for its crawlers: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/dynamic-rendering

Comment: @ОлегАрхипов if you have enough time to make a static version then you have enough time to ensure that Google can understand your dymanic content. Google is very good at working with most JS platforms.