# My Create-React-app blog website's post appeared in google search, why?

Tags: seo, google, google-search, react-js

I was just searching my blog title in google and result blow my mind, How google can read title of my blog that render in client side.

[image: vdevblog]

As i know When googlebot go to any Create-React-app website, it show a blank index.html then how googlebot read content on my blog and appear in google search.

Please describe me how SEO works on Create-React-app.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/130430/is-server-side-rendering-a-must-have-for-good-seo-for-a-react-website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google can crawl, process and index **client-side rendered** applications. There have been discussions on StackExchange on this in the past.

[Is server side rendering a must have for good SEO for a React website?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/130430/is-server-side-rendering-a-must-have-for-good-seo-for-a-react-website)

Therefore, it is no surprise that Google processed and indexed your app. But, the process can be slower compared to server-side rendered pages.